# Open file at specific line in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

In this section: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/codebasics#_additional-command-line-arguments

It states you can use `--goto` to open a file at a specific line. I grep code with AstroGrep and every time I try to use the `--goto` argument VsCode fails to open.

An example argument i'm using which fails:

```
Code.exe --goto C:\filepath\filename.txt:450:11
```

or

```
Code.exe --goto "C:\file path\filename.txt":450:11
```

What is wrong with this *file:line:column* syntax? or is this a bug in vscode?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Seems to be a known issue which was fixed a couple of days ago - see [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/11731)

Workaround until next version:

- Use relative paths
- Use insider version of VSCode

Answer (score 18):

```
Code.exe --goto "C:\file path\filename.txt:450:11"
```

worked for me, take a closer look on the quotation marks.

Answer (score 1):

In MacOS, I achieve the same thing by running

```bash
// `code` should be added to PATH beforehand
code --goto "<filepath>:<linenumber>:<x-coordinates>"
```